# How to use CKEditor in cake php 2.3

Tags: ckeditor, cakephp-2.3

I want to use CKEditor in cake php 2.3, trying a lot but not getting any solutions.
basically I need image upload option in editor from local system.

How could I get success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of research, finally i got the solution for implementing CKEditor with image upload option in cakephp 2.3

For image upload in CKEditor you have to use KCFinder please check the below link you can get the details there

http://cakephpclues.blogspot.in/2012/01/ckeditor-kcfinder-integration-with.html

Also the CKEditor have 3 package

1. Basic Package
2. Standard package
3. Full Package

Also there is an option to customize the editor toolbar
to down load CKEditor please visit -
http://ckeditor.com/download

Answer (score 1):

[Download CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) and extract the files to app/webroot/js/ckeditor

Now in your ctp file add the below code so that the ckeditor.js file will be integrated in the head part of the page.

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->script('ckeditor/ckeditor', array('inline' => false));?>
```

Note: in Layouts/default.ctp confirm that below code is placed in the head part

```
   <?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>
```

Now add the class to the form element to which you want to apply the CKEditor characteristics:

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('myelement', array('class'=>'ckeditor')); ?>
```

Now run your file.. Its DONE..!

In-order to change the other properties of the CKEditor like width, height and toolbar settings add the code in you ctp file. (U can paste it at the end of the ctp file)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    toolbar: [[ 'Bold', 'Italic','Underline','Subscript','Superscript'],],
    width: '700',
    height: '100',
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Editor in website is so important to make the content more beautiful, so we will see how integration CKEditor and CKFinder with cakephp 2.x.

[image]

Creating editor helper:
EditorHelper.php

```
<?php
class EditorHelper extends Helper
{
 function loadCK($id){
 $buff = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 //<![CDATA[
 var editor_$id = CKEDITOR.replace('$id', {customConfig : '/js/editor/config.js'});
 CKFinder.SetupCKEditor( editor_$id, '/js/ckfinder/' );
 //]]>
 </script>";
 return $buff;
 }
}
?>
```

Second we will call it in controller :

```
<?php
    public $helpers = array('Editor');
?>
```

Third we will creating the view :
form.ctp

```
<script src="/js/editor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php echo $this->Form->textarea('Item.content', array('size' => '32')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Editor->loadCK ('PagetextContent');  ?>
```

And After download ckeditor and ckfinder from source http://ckeditor.com and we will put them in /webroot/js/ folder.

That's it, Hope it's helpful.